# What is the replacement for deprecated "\C" in Perl?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to run a Perl script coded before Perl 5.24, and I get the following error:

```
Could not load class (GMP::Group) because : \C no longer supported in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/  
        (?<tag> \xdf \ <-- HERE C \C )                                  # tlv tag 
        (?<len> (?| ( \x81 \C ) | ( \x82 \C \C ) | ( \C ) ) )   # tlv length
        (?<content> (??{ '\C' x binlen2int($+{len}) }) )                # tlv content
    / at /opt/tsm-v1/bin/../lib/GMP/Group.pm line 42.
```

What could be the proper replacement for this line?

```
sub tlvre {
    qr/
        (?<tag> \xdf \C \C )                                    
        (?<len> (?| ( \x81 \C ) | ( \x82 \C \C ) | ( \C ) ) )   
        (?<content> (??{ '\C' x binlen2int($+{len}) }) )                
    /x;
}
```

The code works on Perl 5.18, but as
[`perldiag`](https://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html)
states, `\C` is a "extremely buggy".

> - **\C no longer supported in regex; marked by <-- HERE in m/%s/**
>
>   (F) The \C character class used to allow a match of single byte within a multi-byte utf-8 character, but was removed in v5.24 as it broke encapsulation and its implementation was extremely buggy. If you really need to process the individual bytes, you probably want to convert your string to one where each underlying byte is stored as a character, with utf8::encode().

Now I'm using Perl 5.28.

Comment: This is a very strange thing to want to do. As your reference says, the best way is probably to encode your UTF-8 string to a byte string before processing it. You ask for a "better replacement" for your regex pattern, but a better question would show a sample of your UTF-8 data and explain what you were trying to do.

Comment: Note that Perl doesn't support PCRE. I have changed your tag.

Comment: I'm beginning to think that you're not processing UTF-8 at all, as `\x81` and `\x82` are not valid initial bytes for a UTF-8 character, and `U+0081` and `U+0082` are both little-used control characters. If you are processing an unencoded binary data structure then there is no need for `\C` at all, and you just want `.` with the `/s` modifier and probably `/a` as well.

Comment: Re "*\C is a "extremely buggy"*", It's more than that. `\C` matches against something other than the string being matched against. That makes no sense, so using `\C` makes no sense (and never did). Since `\C` is buggy by design, *and since all uses of `\C` are equally buggy*, it was removed.

Answer (score 2):

A string is an array of integers called characters.

In your case, each character/number appears to a byte read from a stream, and `\xDF \C \C` appears to be trying to match a character/number/byte with value DF<sub>16</sub> followed by any two other characters/numbers/bytes.

For that, you simply want

```
\xDF . .
```

Note that you must also use `/s`. `/s` causes `.` to match any character/number, and thus any byte. (Without `/s`, `.` is equivalent to `[^\x0A]`.)